# Ember view's attribute shared between view's instances?

Tags: ember.js

I have a view:

```
App.PhotoUploadView = Ember.View.extend({
    images: [],
    didInsertElement: function() {
    var that = this;
    var product = this.get('controller').get('model');
    var upimages = product.get('upimages');

    //this.set('images', []);

    upimages.then(function(images) {
        images.forEach(function(image, indexI) {
            var imageObject = new Object();

            imageObject.link = App.appConf.apiPaths.images + image.get('link');
            that.get('images').pushObject(imageObject);
        });
        console.log(that.get('images'))
    });
    }
});
```

So what I'm doing here is define a images array initially empty, and fill it with objects obtained by manipulating a little the model's children...

```
{{#each product in model}}
    {{view App.PhotoUploadView}}
{{/each}}
```

In the App I have many PhotoUploadView inserted at the same time; The thing is that instead of having a different images array for every instance of the PhotoUploadView, I get that every instance has a images array that contains all the images, like if the array is shared between instances;

If I remove comment to this.set('images', []); in the didInsertElement function, then everything works; so the question is: the images array is shared between the PhotoUploadView instances? Or am I missing something...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember sees that as a static property and it applies to all instances of that view.  If you set it as undefined up front, then define it on init (or whenever it's needed) it should fix the issue.

```
App.PhotoUploadView = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function(){
       this._super();
       this.set('images', []);
    }
    images: undefined,
    didInsertElement: function() {
    var that = this;
    var product = this.get('controller').get('model');
    var upimages = product.get('upimages');

    //this.set('images', []);

    upimages.then(function(images) {
        images.forEach(function(image, indexI) {
            var imageObject = new Object();

            imageObject.link = App.appConf.apiPaths.images + image.get('link');
            that.get('images').pushObject(imageObject);
        });
        console.log(that.get('images'))
    });
    }
});
```